# How to create non-ajax post request in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Now I do that in this way.

```
var form=document.createElement('form');
form.setAttribute('method', 'get');
form.setAttribute('action', 'url');
hidden=document.createElement('input');
hidden.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
hidden.setAttribute('name', 'name');
hidden.setAttribute('value', 'value');
form.appendChild(hidden);
form.submit();
```

But I want save the cost on creating the DOMs

Is it possible to submit post request in javascript without DOM?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: If you're concerned about the performance hit of manipulating the DOM; why not have the form hidden. So it's already in the DOM?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid Ajax (`XMLHttpRequest`)? That would save you the (low) cost of creating DOM elements

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

```
document.forms[0].submit()
```

submits the 1st form on the page. And it is the typical way to submit a form in a "non-ajax" way. But the term "non ajax" is misleading in your question, hence the "POST"-verb is a simple http-verb. And there is no difference in using it "ajax"-way or a "non-ajax" way. The artificial difference one could make is: "application/x-www.formurlencoded" is the preferred format of the browser or "application/json" as you are doing it with "ajax".

P.S.: It is hard to answer your question. Of course you could avoid the dynamic creation of a form-element; but you have to use a form element anyways to do a non-ajaxy submit.

Comment: *"And there is no difference in using it "ajax"-way or a "non-ajax" way."* Sure there is. Either you use `XMLHTTPRequest` or you submit the form normally. *""application/x-www.formurlencoded" is the preferred format of the browser or "application/json" as you are doing it with "ajax"."* Very often the data sent via an Ajax request is form-urlencoded as well, since that how form data is normally encoded (related: [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)). The data format does not have much to do with the transport you choose.

Comment: hm. But where is the difference between XMLHTTPRequest and an usual "submit" from the http-point of view? As far as I can see POST is POST, independend from how it was technically initiated. And of course you are right, that very often data sent via ajax could be form-urlencoded; therefore i wrote it would be "artificial".

Comment: Of course there is no difference regarding HTTP, but regarding the JavaScript side. But I understand where you are coming from. The title says "non-ajax post" and of course there is no such thing (POST is POST, as you said). I was more focused on the "JavaScript" point of view. I guess that's the difference how we saw the question :)

Comment: I come from "down under" so to say *G* The term "non ajax-post" is somehow "nonsensical".

Answer (score 1):

I believe you won't actually take much a performance hit doing it the way you are. The big issues with editing the DOM is actually *adding* to the document as it requires re-rendering and stuff.

Comment: DOM manipulation like this is *super trivial*. Elapsed time: 0ms (read: inconsequential) :D While XHR is generally preferred there are advantages to this approach such as returning "Download Files" or "Upload Files via IFrame" (for browsers without such support in XHR/XDR).